# Checkbox group set variable

Tags: sql, forms, checkbox

HTML code:

```
 <form id="formular" method="post" action="input.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="input check_boxes required wish_payment_type">
        <div class="wish_payment_type">
        <span class="checkbox payment-radio">
          <label for="wish_payment_type_1">
            <input class="check_boxes required" id="wish_payment_type_1" name="wish[payment_type][]" type="checkbox" value="ridicare produs"><font face ="Impact" size="+3">Vreau s&#259; ridic un produs</font><br /><br />
          </label>
        </span>
        <span class="checkbox payment-radio">
          <label for="wish_payment_type_2">
            <input class="check_boxes required" id="wish_payment_type_2" name="wish[payment_type][]" type="checkbox" value="predare produs"><font face ="Impact" size="+3">Vreau s&#259; predau un produs</font><br /><br />
          </label>
        </span>
    <span class="checkbox payment-radio">
          <label for="wish_payment_type_3">
            <input class="check_boxes required" id="wish_payment_type_3" name="wish[payment_type][]" type="checkbox" value="informatii"><font face ="Impact" size="+3">Vreau s&#259; adresez o &#238;ntrebare</font><br /><br />
          </label>
        </span>
    <span class="checkbox payment-radio">
          <label for="wish_payment_type_4">
            <input class="check_boxes required" id="wish_payment_type_4" name="wish[payment_type][]" type="checkbox" value="reclamatie"><font face ="Impact" size="+3">Vreau s&#259; fac o sesizare</font><br /><br />
          </label>
        </span>
    <span class="checkbox payment-radio">
          <label for="wish_payment_type_5">
            <input class="check_boxes required" id="wish_payment_type_5" name="wish[payment_type][]" type="checkbox" value="factura storno"><font face ="Impact" size="+3">Vreau s&#259; ridic factura storno</font><br /><br /><br /><br />
          </label>
          <input required="required" type="text" class="inp" name="nume" size="30" placeholder="Introdu aici numele &#351;i prenumele t&#259;u"><br /><br /><br /><br />
          <input id='submit' type="submit" onClick="toUpper()" class="buttons" value="&#206;NREGISTRARE"><br /><br />
      </div>
    </form>
```

Script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var verifyPaymentType = function () {
  var checkboxes = $('.wish_payment_type .checkbox');
  var inputs = checkboxes.find('input');
  var first = inputs.first()[0];

  inputs.on('change', function () {
    this.setCustomValidity('');
  });

  first.setCustomValidity(checkboxes.find('input:checked').length === 0 ? 'Selectați opțiunea dorită.' : '');
}

$('#submit').click(verifyPaymentType);
</script>
```

And variable code from `input.php`:

```
$motiv = $_POST['wish'];
```

Maybe I am stupid and cannot see. It returns me ARRAY text, not the values from checkboxes. Anyone has a clear view about setting the right  `$motiv = $_POST['wish'];` please? Cheers :)

Comment: is `sql` tag relevant here?

Comment: why do you have `sql` tag? I don't see any sql queries or database related issues in your question.

Comment: It gives me error: PHP `Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\input.php on line 21`

Comment: I did not copy the entire sql query.

Comment: can you reproduce your problem here - https://jsfiddle.net/? it is not entirely clear how to reproduce your problem and what you expect as a result.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/imarketsg/rfqq7atz/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88037/discussion-between-bulat-and-bogdan-constantinescu).

Comment: I solved it. I changed from `wish[payment_type][]` to `wish[]` and in input.php I did: `... $nume = $_POST['nume'];
$motiv = $_POST['wish'];
for($i=0; $i < count($motiv); $i++){
$order = "INSERT INTO flux_receptie
   (motiv, nume_client)
   VALUES
   ('$motiv[$i]',
   '$nume')";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $order); 
if($result)
{
  echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index2.php\">"
;} else { echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=www.depanero.ro\">";
}
}`